# Command-line tool for flattening directories

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366028/auto-overwrite-when-flattening-file-structure-in-osx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211911/find-all-files-and-copy-them-to-a-folder-flatten-recursively

I would like one command to just write "flatten" with no arguments and it would have sane default behavior.

Comment: This cmd from the first post you linked to needs the `/directory` as the argument: `find /directory -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -f '{}' /directory ';'`. How do you want to handle that?

Comment: Perhaps you intend to run from the dir you want to flatten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a *NIX system (UNIX/Linux/macOS/etc).

Run this once per terminal session, or put this into your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias flatten='find . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -f {} . ";"'
```

Then run the commands below. These commands can be run repeatedly without side effects. First, `cd` into the directory you would like to flatten, then flatten the files:

```
cd /dir/to/make/flat
flatten
```

**Note:**

**Files with identical names but different paths will overwrite each other.**

**See also:**

- [`find` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)
- [`mv` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)
- [bash aliases](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html)